# Venn Diagram rows in two tables based on overlapping date range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

*Updated with clarification at end*

I have two tables and want to join them in venn diagram fashion so that I end up with the result set below. If there is a row in the date range in Table 2, I want the amount to override (I can figure out that part once I figure out how to link the two tables)

Table 1
`Client#      Start Date      End Date     Amount    Note
 10           9/1/14          9/5/14       100       Something 
 10           9/6/14          9/30/14      200       Nothing 
 20           9/1/14          9/25/14       50       AnotherThing`

Table 2
`Client#      Start Date      End Date     Amount 
 10           9/4/14          9/20/14      150 
 20           9/15/14         9/30/14      300`

Result
`Client#      Start Date      End Date     Amount    Note 
 10           9/1/14          9/3/14       100       Something 
 10           9/4/14          9/5/14       150       Something 
 10           9/6/14          9/20/14      150       Nothing 
 10           9/21/14         9/30/14      200       Nothing 
 20           9/1/14          9/14/14       50       AnotherThing 
 20           9/15/14         9/25/14      300       AnotherThing`

I don't need a record where a record has a date range extended in Table 2 and not Table 1

*Update with clarification*
If I just do a LEFT OUTER JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN I just get 3 results and not 6:

for simplification purposes, I am going to write Start date as SD, End date as ED etc.

This statement

```
SELECT a.Client, a.SD, a.ED, a.Amount, b.SD, b.ED, b.Amount
FROM [Table 1] AS a FULL OUTER JOIN
[Table 2] as b on a.Client=b.Client
AND a.SD<=b.ED AND a.ED>=b.SD
```

Ends up with the following results
`Client#      a.SD         a.ED         a.Amount    b.SD         b.ED         b.Amount
 10           9/1/14       9/5/14       100         9/4/14       9/20/14      150
 10           9/6/14       9/30/14      200         9/4/14       9/20/14      150
 20           9/1/14       9/25/14      50          9/15/14      9/30/14      300`

When what I imagine a first step could be is:
`Client#      a.SD         a.ED         a.Amount    b.SD         b.ED         b.Amount
 10           9/1/14       9/5/14       100
 10           9/1/14       9/5/14       100         9/4/14       9/20/14      150
 10           9/6/14       9/30/14      200         9/4/14       9/20/14      150
 10           9/6/14       9/30/14      200
 20           9/1/14       9/25/14      50
 20           9/1/14       9/25/14      50          9/15/14      9/30/14      300`

Then ultimately be able to convert that result into:
`Client#      SD           ED           Amount
 10           9/1/14       9/3/14       100
 10           9/4/14       9/5/14       150
 10           9/6/14       9/20/14      150
 10           9/21/14      9/30/14      200
 20           9/1/14       9/14/14      50
 20           9/15/14      9/25/14      300`

Where b.Amount overrides a.Amount if it exists and I have a unique record that covers all days in the date range that is represented in table 1 for every client. Is that possible? If so, I can't figure it out. I hope this is more clarifying, please let me know if there is more information that would be helpful.

Comment: What part of it don't you know how to do?

Comment: If it is just client #10, how do I make sure I have the first record in the result line? I.e. if I join on overlapping dates I only imagine getting one record, and not two, including the days where they don't overlap.

Comment: I don't have time to figure out the specific answer, but I can point in the direction I would go.  There needs to be an OR in your where clause, so that you can get both sides of the overlapping dates.  Hope this helps.